# Display code block but also resolve variable within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Rails 7 / Ruby 3**

I'm currently working on a site that requires code examples to be displayed on a page - I can get these to display utilising the extra `%` character trick, however, for some of the examples I need to have a variable within them that is resolved (e.g. like the users' own API key etc...).

Consider I have `@variable = "Resolved Variable"`

`<%%= link_to @variable, variable_path %>`

Outputs on the page explicitly as
`<%= link_to @variable, variable_path %>`

But I really need the `@variable` to resolve and show on the page as:

`<%= link_to "Resolved Variable", variable_path %>`

I've tried all kinds of escaping the variable, but it seems that `<%%=` ensures that nothing following it can be resolved.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Any text you haven't `html_encode`ed will be displayed as plain text.
My suggestion to you is to create a interpolated string that you could use to generate your intended result. For example:

```rb
output_text = "<%= link_to '#{@variable}', variable_path %>"
```

And, not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can get a good UI by adding some Javascript library to format you code in the language in intend (in this case Ruby, it seems).

In case that's interesting to you, check the [Prism](https://prismjs.com) lib, or check how to add it to your project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757947/add-prismjs-to-a-rails-6-webpacker-site)

I hope this helps.
With kind regards,
Rogerio

Answer (score 0):

`<%%` in ERB will simply output `<%`, no more, no less. In particular, it won't attempt to parse the code after `<%%` as Ruby. However, this doesn't mean that you can't have another `<%= ... %>` after `<%%`:

```
require 'erb'

template = <<-EOD
<%%= link_to <%= @variable.inspect %>, variable_path %>
EOD

@variable = "Resolved Variable"

puts ERB.new(template).result
```

The [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#inspect-method) method will add quotes around your string and also escape certain characters as needed.

Output:

```
<%= link_to "Resolved Variable", variable_path %>
```